# access to $route in vue3 / quasar2

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I am using Quasar with API composition and I have an issue.

I just want to get parameters from the current route so within onMounted, I try to use `this.$route.params`, but I always get **"this is undefined"** in console.

```
// src/pages/Level.vue

import { ref, onMounted, computed } from "vue";
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar';

export default {
  name: "LevelPage",
  setup () {
    const $q = useQuasar();
    const $store = useStore();
    const level = ref(null);

    onMounted(()=> {
      console.log(this.$route.params)
    });

    return {
      level,
    }
  },

};
```

I get the same error every time I use this in the setup.

So there must be something I'm not getting. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-provide-inject.html#mutating-reactive-properties  In your Level.vue:

```
import { provide } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    provide('appName', 'vue3')
  }
}
```

And then in any child component where you want to access this variable, inject it:

```
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const appName = inject('appName');
  }
}
```

OR

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()

    onMounted(() => {
      const id = route.params.id
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @PalelPratik. The second solution is what I wanted.